# Pointer address is not incrementing

Tags: c, optimization, pointers

I have already implemented some of the recommendations before in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/16301/how-to-improved-and-optimized-my-squeeze-function). I also improved my code by using pointers. However, what is wrong with address incrementation part below `squeezed_str++`? It seems that address is not incrementing. Please advise.

PS. substring() function is working. :)

```
char *squeeze (char *str, int start_index, int end_index, char *ref_str) {
     char *substr;
     substr = malloc (sizeof (*substr));
     if (substr == NULL) {
          printf ("Unable to allocate memory.\n");
          exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     char *squeezed_str;
     squeezed_str = malloc (sizeof (*squeezed_str));
     if (squeezed_str == NULL) {
          printf ("Unable to allocate memory!\n");
          exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     substr = substring (str, start_index, end_index);
     int substr_len = strlen (substr);
     int refstr_len = strlen (ref_str);

     char chr1, chr2; chr1 = chr2 = '\0';

     for (int i = 0; i < substr_len; i++) {
          chr1 = *(substr+i);
          for (int j = 0; j < refstr_len; j++) {
               chr2 = *(ref_str + j);
               if (chr1 == chr2) {
                    break;
               }
          }
          if (chr1 != chr2) {
               *squeezed_str = *(substr+i);
               squeezed_str++;
          }     
     }

     return squeezed_str;
 } /* end of squeeze() */
```

Comment: The two mallocs are really strange. `sizeof(*subtr) == sizeof(char)`.

Comment: sizeof(char*) gives 4 or 8 bytes typically; strlen(char*) gives the length of the string

Comment: Also, `substr = malloc();` then without transition `substr = substring()`... You're leaking one byte of memory.

Comment: ...and after the 1 byte malloc we immediately leak it by setting the ptr to somthing else...

Comment: @Mat: how strange? i just follow the recommendation [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson6.html)

Comment: @chrismsawi: copy/pasting code isn't the same as "following recommendations". The mallocs you have there make no sense - you're allocating enough space for a single char. Then you don't use that space for `substr` and leak it. Please use a debugger and/or valgrind to narrow down your problem. And

Comment: @chrismsawi , the reccomendation you read was int *ptr = malloc( sizeof(*ptr) ); this allocs space for one integer, you want to alloc space for the content of char *, then malloc(strlen(str)+1) do the trick

Comment: @DavidRF: thanks, it clarified me on the difference between the memory allocation on different data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some improvements with inline advice, not tested:

```
char *squeeze (char *str, int start_index, int end_index, char *ref_str) {
     char *substr = substring (str, start_index, end_index);
         //do not malloc here!, you are doing an assignment later on, so memory leak
         //infact might as well move assignment right here

     char *squeezed_str;
     squeezed_str = malloc (strlen(str)+1); //+ 1 one for null terminator
     if (squeezed_str == NULL) {
          printf ("Unable to allocate memory!\n");
          exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     int substr_len = strlen (substr);
     int refstr_len = strlen (ref_str);
     int squeezeStrIdx = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < substr_len; i++) {
          char chr1 = substr[i]; //using index accessing is nicer
                                 //moved the scope of the variable in
          char chr2 = '\0'; //reduced variable scope, benefit is now resets each loop
          for (int j = 0; j < refstr_len; j++) {
               chr2 = ref_str[j];
               if (chr1 == chr2) {
                    break;
               }
          }
          if (chr1 != chr2) {
               squeezed_str[squeezeStrIdx] = chr1;
               squeezeStrIdx++; //if you modify squeezed_str,
                                //how do you expect to return it at end of method?
          }     
     }

     //this is to null terminate the squeezed_str
     squeezed_str[squeezeStrIdx] = '\0';

     return squeezed_str;
 } /* end of squeeze() */
```

Comment: this actually did the trick. it works! thank you. however, maybe for the last question. i stil don't get why you introduce another variable, squeezeStrIdx to act as the array index. why is this so? please advise more.

Comment: He introduced another variable to not lose the pointer `malloc` returned. See my answer, I did the same thing but using another pointer.

Comment: At the end of the function you return the pointer `squeezed_str`. Your code was incrementing this pointer, so what you were returning would be the pointer at the end of your `squeezed_str`. So the extra variable is to keep track of where we are writing to without needing to alter the `squeezed_str` pointer. It just goes up like 0,1,2,3,4 and is used as an offset into the `squeezed_str` array.

Comment: I just added an improvement, once we are done filling the `squeezed_str`, we should null terminate it. The `squeezeStrIdx` offset is in the right place to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One thing completely flawed is to modify `squeezed_str` at all. This is the address returned by `malloc`. If you modify it you won't be able to `free` that memory area later on. You built a memory leak or even worse, you built a crash when you call `free` at the end.

EDIT:

```
 char *squeeze (const char *str, size_t start_index, size_t end_index, const char *ref_str) 
 /* You don't modify `str` and `ref_str` so it is a good idea to make it visible in the signature of the function, whence the const qualifiers */
 {
 char *substr;   
 /* Snip the memory leak */

 char *squeezed_str = malloc (sizeof (*squeezed_str));
 if (!squeezed_str) {
      fprintf (stderr, "Unable to allocate memory!\n");  /* Error are to be written on stderr */
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);     /* Exitting the app in a function is not good style */
 }

 substr = substring (str, start_index, end_index);
 size_t substr_len = strlen (substr);       /* strlen returns size_t not int */
 size_t refstr_len = strlen (ref_str);

 char chr1 = 0, chr2 = 0;
 char *squeezed_copy = squeezed_str;       /* We use a second pointer to not lose the malloc'ed area */
 for (size_t i = 0; i < substr_len; i++) {
      chr1 = substr[i];                     /* This syntax is simpler (you'll see when you have nested structures */
      for (size_t j = 0; j < refstr_len; j++) {
           chr2 = ref_str[j];
           if (chr1 == chr2) {
                break;
           }
      }
      if (chr1 != chr2)
           *squeezed_copy++ = substr[i];
 }
 /* Add the NUL sentinel */
 *squeezed_copy++ = 0;

 return squeezed_str;
} /* end of squeeze() */
```

This said, I haven't checked the algorithm if it does what you intended to do. In a hunch I would say that using `strstr` would be a better idea.

Comment: this also did the trick! thanks! :)

Comment: one question i would like to raise. you said that "Exitting the app in a function is not good style", why is this so and how should i improved mine? as i read your code, i got many things that are very helpful, consistent implementation. thank you very much.

Comment: Within 1 small program, exiting in a function is not that bad, but if your function is a utility function (destined in the end  to be part of a library) it can be confusing when your program, calling that function, suddenly stops without giving the caller the chance to clean-up (closing files, sockets, signalling, whatever...).

Comment: A function may use a `return error_code` instead. The caller, of course, has then to take action depending on the error returned. For bigger programs it's the better approach, the caller can ignore or handle correctly the errors.

Comment: thank you very much. i'll try to implement your suggestions. :)

Comment: +1 for telling me to give chance for the caller function to clean up.